# Does an Angular factory function need to return something?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would think the answer to this question is "yes," but I was reading through the Angular developer guide (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and stumbled upon this sample code for registering a custom service using the `factory` method:

```
batchModule.factory('routeTemplateMonitor', ['$route', 'batchLog', '$rootScope', 
function($route, batchLog, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    batchLog($route.current ? $route.current.template : null);
  });
}]);
```

As you can see, the factory function in this example doesn't return anything. Is that valid, and if so, how would the `$injector` service handle this case?

PS: `batchLog` is another custom service defined earlier in the guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have to*, even though in the most part of the cases you will *need to*. All javascript functions return undefined if nothing is specified, so it is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not needed for a `Factory` to return something.
I've created a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rzx729xt/) and found out that if the factory doesn't return anything, the value of injected factory is just `undefined` and no error will occur.